# Working with .ui.qml files

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qtquick-designer

In Qt 5.4, the template when creating a new "QtQuick UI File" generates two files: `MyScreen.qml` and `MyScreen.ui.qml`.

The `MyScreen.ui.qml` file seems to be for UI only, since Qt Creator suggests you should only edit it in design mode. That implies that I should be creating UI objects (labels, buttons, etc...) there and somehow referring to them in the `MyScreen.qml` file where the logic would go. In principle this sounds great but, unfortunately Qt doesn't come with any examples of how to work with these 2 files.

Here are the contents of those files:

`MyScreen.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

MyScreen {
}
```

`MyScreen.ui.qml` (I added the Text label in design mode):

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Text {
        id: text1
        x: 144
        y: 151
        width: 103
        height: 31
        text: qsTr("Text")
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
}
```

I tried instantiating a `MyScreen` for use in a `StackView` (see below), but (unsurprisingly) I don't see the label.

`main.qml` :

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    StackView {
        id: stack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: myscreen
    }

    MyScreen {
        id: myscreen
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Any pointers for a QML newbie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating QtQuick UI File in QtCreator, you should name "Component name" and "Component form name" differently.

MyScreen.qml creates a `MyScreen` component, however in the implementation:

```
MyScreen { /* ... */}
```

`MyScreen` creates itself recursively.

In this case, MyScreen.ui.qml creates a `MyScreen` component in the project. At the same time,  the code in MyScreen.qml, which auto-generated by QtCreator, uses the component `MyScreen` created by MyScreen.ui.qml. Unfortunately, `MyScreen` is also the name of MyScreen.qml and makes it creates itself recursively at runtime.

Use different names can solve the problem. For example, rename MyScreen.ui.qml to MyScreenForm.ui.qml.